# Selenium IE Driver is not launching the browser in User Profile

Tags: selenium, selenium-iedriver

I tried to open the URL using IE Driver , the script is working fine as Admin profile but it fails for user profile. The user is under proxy and I have tried the following things PROTECTED MODE SAME LEVEL, REGISTRY SETTING, and same proxy for user and admin.

**CODE:**

```
from  selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
cap['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
cap['IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings'] = True
cap['nativeEvents'] = True
cap['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True
cap['requireWindowFocus'] = True
browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path='C:\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe')
browser.get('https://www.bharti-axagi.co.in/')
```

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/hitesh
>   kumar/PycharmProjects/Open IE/Open IE1.py", line 11, in 
>       browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path='C:\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe')   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py",
>   line 88, in **init**
>       desired_capabilities=capabilities)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 156, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 251, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 320, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 208, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(value) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:

Comment: Hi Aditi, did you try using `copy()` as shown is my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line `cap = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER`

To:

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()
```

This is how it's done in the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities)...

Hope this helps you!